# How to set_value On Dropdown Form Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have this form,but whenever the form_validation return FALSE. The Dropdown form always set to default which was PLEASE SELECT.

How do i Set the value like the input form,i dont know where to put the set_value

**Dropdown Form:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="jenisKelamin">
        <option value="">PLEASE SELECT</option>
           <?php foreach ($system as $d) : ?>
              <?php if ($d->system_type=="JENIS_KELAMIN"): ?>
            <option value="<?= $d->system_value_txt ?>"><?= $d->system_value_txt ?></option>
              <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('jenisKelamin') ?></small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a default dropdown menu, you could use the [`set_select()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select) method on your option input like this :

```php
<div class="form-group">
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="jenisKelamin">
        <option value="">PLEASE SELECT</option>
           <?php foreach ($system as $d) : ?>
              <?php if ($d->system_type=="JENIS_KELAMIN"): ?>
                <option value="<?= $d->system_value_txt ?>" <?php echo set_select('jenisKelamin', $d->system_value_txt); ?> ><?= $d->system_value_txt ?></option>
              <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('jenisKelamin') ?></small>
</div>
```